# Recode list values in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to recode values in a dataframe column which are organized in a list format. I know how to replace string values in a dataframe column but am struggling with how to do this in a list.

Here is a snippet of my data:

```
{0: '[Crime, Drama]',
 1: '[Crime, Drama]',
 2: '[Crime, Drama]',
 3: '[Action, Crime, Drama, Thriller]',
 4: '[Crime, Drama]',
 5: '[Biography, Drama, History]',
 6: '[Crime, Drama]',
 7: '[Adventure, Drama, Fantasy]',
 8: '[Western]',
 9: '[Drama]'}
```

For example, I'd like to recode all Crimes to Thrillers and Biography to History.

I know the below works for replacing string values

```
df.loc[df['genre']=='Crime']='Thriller'
```

but how do I modify this for a list?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The code used to create this dataframe (with data extracted from the IMDB database) is:

```
# these are the variables we want to (ie are able to) extract from the movie object
metadata = ('title', 'rating', 'genre', "plot", "language", "runtime", "year", "color", "country" , "votes")
#creates dataframe with variable name headers
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(250, len(metadata)), columns=metadata) 

#these are all different data types, including lists, this makes it compile
df = df.astype('object')
#populate df with movie objects
for i in range(250):
    for j in metadata:
        df.loc[i, j] = movies_list[i].get(j)

# convert to the right data types:
metadata_dict_dtypes = {"title": unicode,
                        "rating": float,
                        "genre":list,
                        "plot": str,
                        "language":list,
                        "runtime":list,
                        "year":int,
                        "color":list,
                        "country":list ,
                        "votes":int}
for colname, my_dtype in metadata_dict_dtypes.iteritems():
    df[colname] = df[colname].astype(my_dtype)
```

Comment: do 0-9 represent different columns or rows in your dataframe?

Comment: Different rows.

Comment: '[Crime, Drama]' (quotes on the outside, not inside, the brackets) looks like a string not a list to me. Can you show the code to actually create this dataframe so I know exactly what you're working with?

Comment: Sure, just updated the post. The data is coming from the IMDB database so the df is populated with movie objects that we already downloaded.

Comment: Running that code just throws an error for me because I don't have 'movies_list'. Please see tips to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: We appreciate your edit but as is, code is not compilable. Please include all `import` lines and necessary date items like *movies_list*. And where is *unicode* dervied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is correctly formatted as a list in the DataFrame. You could write a function that takes a row, and genre name change map as arguments and apply it to the DataFrame. For example

```
name_map = {'Crime': 'Thriller', 'Biography': 'History'}
def change_names(row, name_map):
    for name in name_map:
        if name in row.genre:
            row.genre[row.genre.index(name)] = name_map[name]
    return row
df = df.apply(lambda row: change_name(row, name_map), axis=1)
```

It's not vectorized, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating with list comprehension. Below uses a one-column dataframe of *Genre* lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Genre': [['Crime', 'Drama'],
                             ['Crime', 'Drama'],
                             ['Crime', 'Drama'],
                             ['Action', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller'],
                             ['Crime', 'Drama'],
                             ['Biography', 'Drama', 'History'],
                             ['Crime', 'Drama'],
                             ['Adventure', 'Drama', 'Fantasy'],
                             ['Western'],
                             ['Drama']]})    
print(df)
#                               Genre
# 0                    [Crime, Drama]
# 1                    [Crime, Drama]
# 2                    [Crime, Drama]
# 3  [Action, Crime, Drama, Thriller]
# 4                    [Crime, Drama]
# 5       [Biography, Drama, History]
# 6                    [Crime, Drama]
# 7       [Adventure, Drama, Fantasy]
# 8                         [Western]
# 9                           [Drama]

df['Genre'] = [['Thriller' if i=='Crime' else i for i in m] for m in df['Genre']]
print(df)
#                                  Genre
# 0                    [Thriller, Drama]
# 1                    [Thriller, Drama]
# 2                    [Thriller, Drama]
# 3  [Action, Thriller, Drama, Thriller]
# 4                    [Thriller, Drama]
# 5          [Biography, Drama, History]
# 6                    [Thriller, Drama]
# 7          [Adventure, Drama, Fantasy]
# 8                            [Western]
# 9                              [Drama]
```